# Listview...how to conditionally replace a value with a string

Tags: java, android, listview

my ANDROID app presents a listview, from a database cursor and XML, that needs to replace the values in a column with various words based on the integer value contained in the cursor.  For example, if the value is -1, replace it with the word "Invalid", but if the value is >= 0 then just display the value.

I was under the impression this could magically be done via XML...  TIA.

Comment: what programming language are you using?

Comment: Doh, I left out Android/Java...

Answer (score 0):

you can either use JS regular expressions ([regexp](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_regexp.asp)) to replace them or use PHP Class

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't state what language you are using, there might be some difference to the language of your choice:

```
yourValue = ( '-1' == yourValue ) ? 'Invalid' : yourValue;
```

This will replace the contents of yourValue with 'Invalid' if it is -1 or let it stay the same.

You need to modify this depending on how you access your variables (i.e. dollar signed prefixed: $yourValue).

If your language is type-aware, you might want to make sure that yourValue is already a string.

This is what you should do when printing the output or while reading the content of your file. XML itself does not change the values for you.

Comment: Thanks favo.  Makes sense that I need to do the formatting first.  The data has a max of about 20 rows, so I'll read in the values, format them and place in an array, then stuff the array into the listview.